# best practice store data in local storage

Tags: angular, local-storage, frontend

I'm currently working on an Angular application and when the user is authenticated I'd like to store some data in locale storage. I'm wondering if I store the user level access in it? Is that a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly store user authentication token in local storage, but it is best just to keep it around during the session, so use session storage is a better choice which has the same APIs, they only differ in semantics

local storage -> persists beyond the current session

session storage -> is destroyed when the browser is closed.

Local storage and session storage are subject to the same CORS policy as other static resources, so you are safe to store user authentication data in there

Comment: So it means I can store in session storage if my user is admin or just a simple user ? I want to do that for performance issue.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to store authentication in local storage because each user only needs to be kept authenticated when they are using the app,  and when they leave, you want to leave no trace of their identity around. Again, where you want to store it is a matter of choice, if you want it to persist beyond the current session, so the next time you don't have to fetch it which is great performance-wise, use local storage, just make sure that if this data does get changed, the user can still use it to authenticate themselves

Comment: Forgot to address your question, you can store whatever you want in local/session storage, whatever you want to store depends on your use cases, just don't store too much data, the supposed limit is 16MB.